# Seeing JUnit reports in GitLab using GitLab CI

Tags: junit, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We want to use GitLab CI to run JUnit tests periodically (every day) and to have a place to see the results of said tests.
Reading GitLab's docs, it seems that the `artifacts:reports:junit` directive automatically collects XML JUnit reports to display them in Merge Requests.

What I want to know is, are these visible in other places than merge request pages in the GitLab UI? Our tests are going to be ran based on a schedule, merge-request/push/commit pipelines are going to be entirely avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to know is, are these visible in other places than merge request pages in the GitLab UI?

**Yes**, for jobs that store artifacts there is a download button in GitLab UI **Project -> CI/CD** views.

Gitlab [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-artifacts) have all described with examples.

Comment: I did know this but I was wondering if there was directly a widget that shows the JUnit test results. Merge Requests in GitLab have specific widgets that show JUnit reports, I was wondering if that particular widget is visible in other places than merge requests